# Assign multiple DisplayMembers in MultiColumn ListBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, datasource

I have a ListBox that has `IEnumerable` `List<PhoneNumber>` as `DataSource`.
PhoneNumber class has 2 properties Number and Type.
I want to display Number and Type in separate columns so I set `MultiColumn` property to true bur now how do I assign `DisplayMembers` to individual columns?
And since we are on a topic of ListBox, how do you change background color of individual lines in ListBox?

Comment: Why not just use a `GridView` or a `ListView`? Those are built for multi-column support, `ListBox` is built for a single column.

Answer (score 1):

A multicolumn [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) places items into as many columns as are needed to make vertical scrolling unnecessary. It does not span single item into many columns. And, of course it does not support several `DisplayMembers`. Use [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or (better) [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead - both controls have columns, and allow to map different object properties to those columns. Also it's very easy to set background color to individual rows in [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - use [DataBindingsComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is WPF

[GridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ListPhoneNumber">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Number" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Type" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I believe OP talks about WinForms, because there is no DisplayMember property for WPF ListBox

Answer (score 0):

As a way around, I gave up on MultiColumn. I added second ListBox and placed it next to the first one so they look like one object. I assigned DataSource to be the one of the other ListBox but I assigned DisplayMember to be Type. At runtime both objects look like they are one, selection always highlights both listboxes at the same time as they have the same datasource. In addition I have a nice visual effect because selection changes in first listbox OnClick and replicates to the other one OnKeyUp.